# What are the rules for launch-prefix?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to see what I can do with the seemingly powerful `launch-prefix` for `roslaunch`.  However, I can't quite decipher when it will accept it and when it throws

```
RLException: Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token):
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341305/what-are-the-rules-for-launch-prefix?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> RLException: Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token):
> ```

The particular error you show just tells us that you have something in that attribute which is not valid XML.

As `.launch` files are XML, you need to ensure that whatever you have in the `launch-prefix` attribute is valid XML as well. This means: no special characters, no `"`, no `&`, etc.

You'll have to escape/encode those characters before putting them in that attribute. I 'd suggest looking up some sites about XML and entity encoding.

> What are the rules for launch-prefix?

Ignoring the "valid XML" aspect, here are some guidelines:

- it needs to be something that can actually be executed
- it needs to be something which does not interfere with `roslaunch`'s process monitoring (or: if it would interfere you'll just run into problems when trying to shutdown your launch session)
- it needs to be able to process the "rest of the command line" (ie: path and name of node binary, any additional args to the node binary)

there may be more, perhaps other board members can contribute.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1